# How to search for substring containing "(" in python dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe column of MLB teams with pitchers in brackets, for example "san francisco giants (m moore)".  I'm trying to match some other data with this but having trouble with the str.contains method.  For example str.contains("san fr") comes up true but str.contains("giants (m") returns false.  Think it might have something to do with the "(" but can't work out how.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the parenthesis using `\`, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':"san francisco giants (m moore)"},index=[0])
df.a.str.contains("giants \(m")
```

Result:

```
>>> df.a.str.contains("giants \(m")
0    True
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'm using str.contains(re.escape("giants (m")) to get around it